# When is sina +sinb +sinc =0 ? And when is cos x + cosy+ cos z =0?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a specific condition for this to take place for angles a,b,c  or x,y,z?
And also when will sina +sinb+sinc=cosa+cosb+cosc =0?
Not some problem or smth was just wondering.

Comment: For the last one, let $A=\sin a - \cos a$, $B=\sin b - \cos b$, $C=\sin c - \cos c$ to get $A+B+C=0$

Comment: @Farrukh Ataev didn't get you?

Comment: @Shuri2060 what does that prove ??

Comment: Not entirely sure yet, but it looks like it'll help

Comment: A ,B,C are assumed variables and what does their total adding up to zero prove ??

Comment: imo it makes it look like manipulation look easier. I might be wrong. $|\sin x -
 \cos x| \le \sqrt2$ by differentiation though.

Comment: However, solving the first part will, of course, give a direct solution to the last part, so perhaps ignore that for now.

Comment: I'm new to calculus so please bear with me ,how did you get $|\sinx - \cosx| <= \sqrt2$ by differentiation? What did you differentiate?

Comment: Differentiate that expression. When the derivative is 0, then that expression is at either a maximum or minimum.

Comment: *that* equation ? Which one 

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x - \cos x)$

Comment: Note $f'(k)=0 \iff k$ is a minimum or maximum of $f$. Let $f(x)=\sin x - \cos x$. $f'(x)=\cos x + \sin x$. $f'(k)=0 \implies \cos x + \sin x=0 \implies \tan x = -1 \implies x = -\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$.

Comment: @FarrukhAtaev `Divide by 2R` The question doesn't say that $a,b,c$ are the angles of a triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

---

Let $A=\sin a$, $B=\sin b$, $C=\sin c$. Then $A,B,C \in [-1,1]$.

Now you have $A+B+C=0$, and we can conclude two of these variables are free.

Therefore the solution set for $(A,B,C)$ is $\{(\alpha,\beta,-\alpha-\beta): \alpha,\beta\in [-1,1]\}$

Therefore the solution set for $(a,b,c)$ is $\{(2k_1\pi+\sin^{-1}\alpha,2k_2\pi+\sin^{-1}\beta,2k_3\pi+\sin^{-1}(-\alpha-\beta)): \alpha,\beta\in [-1,1],k_1, k_2, k_3, \in\mathbb Z\}$

Similarly, the solution set for $(x,y,z)$ is $\{(2k_1\pi+\cos^{-1}\alpha,2k_2\pi+\cos^{-1}\beta,2k_3\pi+\cos^{-1}(-\alpha-\beta)): \alpha,\beta\in [-1,1],k_1, k_2, k_3, \in\mathbb Z\}$

---

Now for the last question, you want to find the intersection of these two solution sets.

Comment: `α,β∈[−1,1]` That's not enough, you also need $\alpha+\beta \in [−1,1]$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks - keep missing out things..